# Design issue with iPhone notch (x - 12 -13 ) how to fix content overlapped with sass or angular 12

Tags: html, angular, sass

I am working on a responsive App  and I have an issue that the content of the header is cropped at iPhone 12 or 13 pro with notch but in Android, it's working fine

I tried padding and margins but not working fine and also safe area.

help please.

*Note:
I need this issue to fix vertical view only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.